# How to draw diagrams?

Tags: graphics, diagrams

I need to learn how to draw diagrams. Could you please help me from the screenshot below...

[image]

...and this MWE?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
        
  \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the lern how to draw diagrams, you must first decide which package you like to use (`pstrick`, `tikz`,...) than look in ther documentation. Also here on site is plenty of answers which use on of mentioned packages, Also, for example for `tikz` exist site with hundreds of examples  (https://texample.net//).

Answer (score 6):

You can just use dashed lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[dash pattern=on 2pt off 1cm-2pt,line width=2pt,dash phase=2pt] 
        (0,0) -| (2,6) -| cycle;
    \draw[dash pattern=on 2pt off 3pt,line width=2pt]   
     (5,3) circle[radius=5/pi];
   \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{A caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]